# WPF Button No Border No Background

Tags: wpf, button, styles

I just need a button so simple that it looks like a TextBlock.  Some time ago I saw an answer on SO to style the button based on a static style for a button in a menu but I cannot find that answer (and I have been searching for an hour).  Does anyone know what system style I am referring to and the syntax to apply that style to a button?

Comment: If you want an WPF Button with no border and no background you can always set Button's Background property to Transparent, and Button's BorderThickness property to 0.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

Is it maybe the style used for a button in a ToolBar that you're referring to? The ToolBar control overrides the Button style so they appear flat.  You can apply that style to a button like this...

```
<Button Style="{StaticResource {x:Static ToolBar.ButtonStyleKey}}" />
```

Comment: This has the benefit that you don't have to implement styles for when the button is moused-over or pressed

Comment: Awesome, just what I was looking for!!

Comment: This is a great approach. The only thing I see is that once you click on the button, button gets selected and it remains as is forever until you click in another button or component.

Answer (score 43):

If you want a button that looks like a `TextBlock`, you can make a button that **is** a `TextBlock`.

```
<Button Content="I'm a Button; click me">
    <Button.Template>
        <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
            <TextBlock Text="{TemplateBinding Content}" />
        </ControlTemplate>
    </Button.Template>
</Button>
```

Comment: Good answer and a better answer for my problem but lanR had the system style I was looking for.  +1

Comment: this method allows one to substitute in a clickable `<Image />` (without all the button chrome).

Comment: You may need to specify the type before Content for this to work.  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4572304/wpf-inheriting-from-window

Comment: I would not consider this metro-style though since you don't get the features of mouseover and such without a lot more pain of manually inserting that code.

Comment: Is there a way to resize the button to the amount of text automatically?